# How to get SObject type from object Id using REST API?

Tags: api, sobject, rest

I have an object id that is a "parent id" of a specific Attachment object (e.g., b3KD0000119wDTlMAN). I'd like to understand what type this object belongs to, to query for it's details. It can also be a Custom Object. Currently I only work through REST API. Can this be done using REST API?

Comment: Take a look at my answer for a more direct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the parent's type directly in the SOQL:

```
SELECT ParentId, Parent.Type FROM Attachment WHERE Id = ...
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
{
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Attachment",
                "url": "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Attachment/..."
            },
            "ParentId": "...",
            "Parent": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Name",
                    "url": "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Opportunity/..."
                },
                "Type": "Opportunity"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalSize": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot sfdcfox. This is a much better solution indeed.

Comment: yes i agree, i was not aware about this thanks @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

You can get object type by Id using dynamic apex

```
Schema.SObjectType token = objIds[0].getSObjectType();
```

where objIds is a list of Ids.

Read more on  [this link.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm)

You have to add all these methods (as per your requirement) in your REST service provider class.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there is no such function available but you can create your own library to find object using first 3 letter of id here is the list for some standard salesforce object.https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US

Comment: You should be able to query `parent.type` in the query.